# How to preserve conditional comments in <html> element in a Diazo theme?

Tags: plone, diazo

I have a Diazo theme file which is based on the [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com). The theme uses conditional comments on the `<html>` element to identify particular versions of Internet Explorer, e.g.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!-- Consider adding an manifest.appcache: h5bp.com/d/Offline -->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

However, when the theme is applied Diazo seems to strip away these conditional comments and only the last

```
<!--<![endif]-->
```

is left in the final markup producing something like

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="no-js" lang="en" xml:lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
```

with an unmatched `endif`. Using conditional comments within the `<html>` tag (e.g. inside `<head>` or further down in the document) seems to work fine.

Examples of a theme and rules files which have this issue are available at

https://github.com/hexagonit/hexagonit.themeskel/blob/master/hexagonit/themeskel/templates/less_theme/+namespace_package+/+package+/theme_resources

I'm using plone.app.theming 1.0b8 with the associated KGS versions from good-py.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in Diazo, please add it to the Plone bug tracker with component 'Diazo'.

Answer (score 0):

A work around for this could be to use conditional comments on the `<body>` tag, but Diazo must also add a few classes to the body tag for Plone, which would break it in <=IE8.

```
<merge attributes="class" css:theme="body" css:content="body" />
```

So a 3rd rate work around could be to use contional comments on a div block like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]> <div class="no-js ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 7]> <div class="no-jsie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 8]> <div class="no-js ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <div class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

    <div id="content"></div>

  </div><!-- Browser Detection -->
</body>
</html>
```

Given the general fuglyness of Plone's generated html, I could live with this.